# Modelate amount in ManyToMany relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, database-design, many-to-many

I'm creating a simple e-shop. It's `java` based application using `hibernate` for `ORM`. As a database I use `MySQL`.

I have there these three `entities`: Order, Product and Order_contains_product for joining those two tables in `ManyToMany` relationship. I was thinking about adding a new column "amount" to this Order_contains_product table, because now, I add a new row for every single piece of product in the order - this might cause problems after a few years.
So I've added there a column, but I've lost benefits from this `ManyToMany` relationship - now every single time I need to get amount of a particular product in an order, I need to make an extra query just to get answer to this simple question. And I have to do it as may times as the count of products in order is. Is this a good approach or can I do it somehow better - it looks quite unefficient to me? Any ideas or suggestions? Here an illustration of my data model.

[image: Model diagram]